# Password issue upon accessing two different Postgres databases in shell script

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell, scripting, postgresql-9.1

I'm writing a shell script that will perform a pg_dump from one server, and later it will restore the dump into a database on another server.

To access the Postgres database on the first server, I use export PGPASSWORD in order to avoid a password prompt.

When I perform the restore on the Postgres database for the second server, I am prompted for a user password. I tried to re-declare export PGPASSWORD (since the password for this database is different), but this does not work. I'm suspecting it has something to do with the fact that I have to double SSH hop in order to access the second database:

```
export PGPASSWORD=******
perform pg_dump
...
export PGPASSWORD=********
cat out.sql | ssh -i .ssh/server1.pem root@dev.hostname.com "ssh -i .ssh/server2 \
0.0.0.0 psql -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 DBNAME"
```

The above results in:

```
Password for user postgres:
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a file in your home directory with name .pgpass & give the password details there :

like :

cat .pgpass

## hostname:port:database:username:password

localhost:2323:test_db:test_user:test123**

Try this one. Hope your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The `.ssh/environment` file is what you want. I think that file needs to be on server1, though, and server2 needs to be configured to allow users to modify their environment (via the `PermitUserEnvironment` option. See `man ssh` under "ENVIRONMENT" for more details.